# how to select null column valued row if there is no not null valued column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a bit strange kind of requirement. will try to explain a simple table.

I have `User` table and here are the records.
[image]

Now I want the output as,[image]

I tried all possible solutions like `case/collate`, but no success. Basically i want all the users with their counties but if the country is not present select the with null valued country.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  You need to explain the logic.

Comment: What should happen when there is more than one country for a user ?

Comment: No, there can not be more than one courntry for a user.

Answer (score 1):

NULL is treated as an unknown value in GROUP BY in most dbms:
So use a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT name,age,MAX(country) AS country 
FROM table_a 
GROUP BY name,age;
```

Comment: Can not use group by because of some reasons i have bigger query , I just given a small part only

Comment: By using the `GROUP BY` you can get this set sorted and then `JOIN` the other data back to do the other operations on that.

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy `select * from (select row_number()over(partition by name,age order by country desc) as rn, name,.. ) a where rn = 1`

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you can use `distinct on`.  I think this is what you want:

```
select distinct on (t.name) t.*
from t
order by name, ( (country is not null)::int ) desc;
```

This might be the most efficient method if you want one row per `name`.

Another efficient method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.country is not null
union all
select t.*
from t
where t.country is null and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.name = t.name and t2.county is not null);
```

This is more appropriate if you want multiple rows per name.